# How to remove previous page in react native using @react-navigation/native

Tags: react-native, navigation

I want to finish my splash screen in react native how can I do this I have search a lot but did not find anything I'm using this @react-navigation/native.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `finish my splash screen` can you clarify please

Comment: Actually i have 3 Screens A,B, C  first i move on A then B and then C and here if i press back button then i  want to just move on A not B

Comment: Like if i press logout button then i move on login screen but after pressing back button on login screen i'm moving on home page

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen)

import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'

```
export default class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        // do stuff while splash screen is shown
        // After having done stuff (such as async tasks) hide the splash screen
        SplashScreen.hide();
    }
}
```